# mysql- Update query with respect to select query

Tags: mysql

hi here i have two tables named as test and test2.

test is as follows

[image]

test2 is as follows

[image]

i am using below sql code to get the below output.

```
UPDATE `test`
SET `availability` = 'ok'
WHERE
    `id` = '(SELECT
test.id
FROM
test2
INNER JOIN test ON test.id = test2.PId)';
```

I requires below output. but it outcomes no any output. kindly help. any mistakes done by my end or if there is any best mothod to get below output, kindly mention

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of

```
UPDATE test 
INNER JOIN test2 on test.id = test2.PId
SET test.availability = 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't need an update, just a query with a join:

```
SELECT test.id, test.name, CASE WHEN teste2.pid IS NOT NULL THEN 'OK' END
FROM   test
JOIN   test2 ON test.id = test2.pid
```

Comment: hi i jut need to update the value to the 'availability' column is that possible, i hope  i should use an update query to enter ok value for the availability column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work.but hey we all try here right..

```
UPDATE `test`
SET `availability` = 'ok'
WHERE
`id` in '(SELECT
PId from test2)';
```

I don't get , why do you need inner join.You only need those id's that are present in test2 table,then just take it.
although  i have used 'in' keyword,try with '=' also but i doubt it will work because inner query is returning a list of id's.thanks.